# Best way to combine the module pattern with closures

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, closures

I'm currently trying to implement some common JS concepts
in little projects to understand better how to use them.

I've been working on a simple game, trying to
understand and use the module pattern and closures. 
I'm using the module pattern from Stoyan Stefanov's 'patterns'
book.

I'm struggling to understand how best to mix modules and
closures.

I'd like to know if I'm organising the following code in a 
sensible way?  If so, my question is: what's the best way 
to modify the code so that in the `$(function(){})` I have 
access to the `update()` function?

```
MYAPP.utilities = (function() {

    return {
        fn1: function(lives) {
            //do stuff
        }
    }
})();

MYAPP.game = (function() {

    //dependencies
    utils = MYAPP.utilities

    return {
        startGame: function() {

            //initialisation code
            //game state, stored in closure
            var lives = 3;
            var victoryPoints = 0;

            function update(){
                utils.fn1(lives);
                //do other stuff
            }

        }
    }
})();

$(function(){
    MYAPP.game.startGame();

    //Want to do this, but it won't work 
    //because I don't have access to update

    $('#button').on('click',MYAPP.game.update) 

});
```

I've come up with a couple of options which would work, but
I'd like to know if they're good practice, and what the best
option is.

Options:

(1) Bind `$('#button').on('click', ...)` as part of the 
startGame initialisation code.

(2) Assign the `update()` function to a variable, and
return this variable from the startGame function,  So in 
`$(function(){})` we could have 
`updatefn = MYAPP.game.startGame();` and then 
`$('#button').on('click',MYAPP.game.update)`

(3)? Is there a better way?

Thank you very much for any help,

Robin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, to access the `update` function in that fashion it will have to exposed in the returned object.

```
return {
    update: function() {
        [...]
    },
    startGame: function() {
        [...]
        this.update();
    }
}
```

Calling `obj.method()` automatically sets the `this` reference inside this `method` call to `obj`. That is, calling `MYAPP.game.startGame()` sets `this` to `MYAPP.game` inside this `startGame` method call. More details about this behavior [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#As_an_object_method).

You will also want to move the `lives` variable to a common scope which is accessible by both `startGame` and `update` methods, which is exactly what the closure is for:

```
MYAPP.game = (function() {

    [...]
    var lives; //private/privileged var inside the closure, only accessible by
               //the returned object's function properties

    return {
        update: function() {
            utils.fn1(lives);
        },
        startGame: function() {
            [...]
            lives = 3; //sets the closure scope's lives variable
            [...]
            this.update();
        }
    }
})();
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/X7SHN/)

In this case you will need some method to set the `lives` variable when you want to change it. Another way would be to make the `lives` variable public as well by making it a property of the returned object and accessing it through `this.lives` inside of the methods.

**NOTE:** If you simply pass a reference to the function object stored as property of the returned object as in:

```
$('#button').on('click', MYAPP.game.update);
```

The `this` reference inside the click handler will **not** point to `MYAPP.game` as the function reference that has been passed will be called directly from the jQuery core instead of as an object's member function call - in this case, `this` would point to the `#button` element as jQuery event handlers set the `this` reference to the element that triggered the handler, as you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/X7SHN/1/).

To remedy that you can use [`Function.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
$('#button').on('click', MYAPP.game.update.bind(MYAPP.game));
```

Or the old function wrapper trick:

```
$('#button').on('click', function() {
    MYAPP.game.update(); //called as method of an obj, sets `this` to MYAPP.game
});
```

This is important when the `this` keyword is used inside the `update` method.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues in your code. First, `update()` function is not visible outside the object your creating on the fly. To make it part of `game` object it has to be on the same level as `startGame`.

Also, if you declare `var lives = 3` it will be a local variable and it won't be visible outside `startGame()` function, as well as `victoryPoints`. These two variable have to be visible in some way (via closure or as object fields).

Finally, attaching `MYAPP.game.update` as an event listener will attach just that function, preventing you from using all other object methods/functions. Depending on what you want to do you might prefer to pass a closure like `function() { MYAPP.game.update() }` instead.

Your code should look something like:

```
MYAPP.utilities = (function() {

    return {
        fn1: function(lives) {
            console.log(lives);
        }
    }
})();

MYAPP.game = (function() {

    //dependencies
    utils = MYAPP.utilities

    var lives;
    var victoryPoints;

    return {
        startGame: function() {

            //initialisation code
            //game state, stored in closure
            lives = 3;
            victoryPoints = 0;
        },

        update: function() {
            utils.fn1(lives);
            //do other stuff
        }
    }
})();

$(function(){
    MYAPP.game.startGame();

    //Want to do this, but it won't work 
    //because I don't have access to update

    $('#button').on('click', MYAPP.game.update) 

});
```

(**[DEMO on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R9RM5/)**)